# Can I remove the redundancy in this code?

Tags: go

I have this go code

```
type Collections struct {
    Object string `json:"object"`
    Data   []struct {
        Object     string      `json:"object"`
        ID         string      `json:"id"`
        Groups     interface{} `json:"groups"`
        ExternalID interface{} `json:"externalId"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
type Members struct {
    Object string `json:"object"`
    Data   []struct {
        Object                string      `json:"object"`
        ID                    string      `json:"id"`
        UserID                string      `json:"userId"`
        Name                  string      `json:"name"`
        Email                 string      `json:"email"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
type Groups struct {
    Object string `json:"object"`
    Data   []struct {
        Object      string `json:"object"`
        ID          string `json:"id"`
        Name       string `json:"name"`
        AccessAll  bool   `json:"accessAll"`
        ExternalID string `json:"externalId"`
    } `json:"data"`
}


func bwRequestWithBT(uri string) []byte {

    url := endpoint + uri
    // Create a new request using http
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    // Send req using http Client
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Err(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    return body
}

func (c *Collections) APIData() {
    err := json.Unmarshal(RequestWithBT("/collections"), &c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while unmarshalling collection")
    }
}

func (m *Members) APIData() {
    err := json.Unmarshal(RequestWithBT("/members"), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while unmarshalling members")
    }
}

func (g *Groups) APIData() {
    err := json.Unmarshal(RequestWithBT("/groups"), &g)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while unmarshalling groups")
    }
}

var members Members
members.APIData()

var groups Groups
groups.APIData()

var collection Collections
collection.APIData()
```

Where upon making API calls you get different JSON responses back.

I feel that I am repeating myself by redefining `APIData` three times.

Is there a way to do something like this in Golang?

```
func (object GenericObject) APIData(uri string){
    err := json.Unmarshal(RequestWithBT(uri), &object)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while unmarshalling")
    }
}


var members Members
var groups Groups
var collection Collections

members.APIData("/members")
groups.APIData("/groups")
collection.APIData("/collections")
```

Or something on this tune?

Answer (score 1):

We can easily answer this question if we understand, how and when it used in future.

Let's assume that you're simply trying to DRY on method that makes request and parses response.

Then consider having a "requester" method and supported interface:

```
type Entity interface {
    URI() string
}

func load(entity Entity) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(RequestWithBT(entity.URI()), &entity)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while unmarshalling members")
    }
}
```

Then we can use it like that:

```
var members Members
var groups Groups
var collection Collections

load(&members)
load(&groups)
load(&collection)
```

Surely, we should define an `URL()` method on each entity.

I don't see good option to use generics in this situation but you can search for some insights there: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics